# Keep rows with certain type based on a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that i want to clean, i have a column with some integer and some timestamp. I want to remove the rows with the integer value in the columns, and only keep the rows with timestamp.

```py
df.col.unique() #gives

array([Timestamp('2017-05-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-05-30 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2017-05-25 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-05-24 00:00:00'),
       43249, 43225, 43245, 43228, 43246,
       Timestamp('2018-09-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-09-04 00:00:00')]
```

I want to remove the rows with int values and keep timestamp dates.

Comment: can you provide a sample input and desired output for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to filter your dataframe

```
df[~df.col.map(lambda x: isinstance(x,int))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
# Example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2019-01-01', 2, '2019-01-02', 3, '2019-01-03']})

    timestamp
0  2019-01-01
1           2
2  2019-01-02
3           3
4  2019-01-03


df[pd.to_numeric(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce').isna()]

    timestamp
0  2019-01-01
2  2019-01-02
4  2019-01-03
```